# mysql BETWEEN 2 time(s)

Tags: mysql, time

I've been nosing the forum and found posts similar but not working for me, so here goes.

I am trying 2 things, firstly: I have created a checkbox which when selected will show the results of shops open. `shop_open` and `shop_close` are my columns in use here which are of `time` data type (`07:00:00` for example). When the user selects and submits the form with checkbox ticked, I want something like `CURTIME()` to check the current time, hour and minute only, and then see if the current hour:minute is between the `shop_open` and `shop_close` times, which should display shops which are open at the time submitted.

The second option was to have 2 input boxes to enter open and/or close times to see if the data matches similar to above. The first option sounds better to me, fiddling with the 2 options has resulted in steps backwards.

Here is my query:

```
"SELECT shops.*, services.*, ratings.*, temp.total as final_total, CONCAT(shop_number, ' ', shop_location, ' ', shop_city, ' ', shop_province, ' ', shop_postcode) AS address FROM shops 
 inner join services on shops.shop_id=services.shop_id
 inner join ratings on shops.shop_id=ratings.shop_id
 inner join (select SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience )/(6) / COUNT(shop_id) AS total, shop_id FROM ratings GROUP BY shop_id ) as temp on shops.shop_id=temp.shop_id HAVING temp.total >= '$search_total_rating'
 AND CURTIME() BETWEEN shop_open AND shop_close
 AND address LIKE '%$search_shop_address%' AND shop_name LIKE '%$search_shop_name%' ORDER BY shop_name ASC
```

I am aware this is messy and complex query but it works great minus this issue. 
The code you suggested, I was already using but in a different circumstance because of my messy complex query, i imagine i've put it in the wrong place:s

I am not tring to use 
             '$search_open_now' BETWEEN shop_open AND shop_close 
instead of getting the current time and it returns the wrong results :(

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will do what I think you want:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE CURTIME() BETWEEN shop_open AND shop_close;
```

Comment: i have similiar, but the WHERE does not fit into my query so I am using AND because I have other criteria that may be met

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT field_names FROM table_name WHERE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i'), ':00') BETWEEN shop_open AND shop_close
```

Should ignore the seconds for you.

---

Update: Something like this seems to work for me, moving the WHERE before the HAVING clause

```
SELECT shops.*, services.*, ratings.*, temp.total as final_total, CONCAT(shop_number, ' ', shop_location, ' ', shop_city, ' ', shop_province, ' ', shop_postcode) AS address FROM shops 
inner join services on shops.shop_id=services.shop_id
inner join ratings on shops.shop_id=ratings.shop_id
inner join (select SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience )/(6) / COUNT(shop_id) AS total, shop_id FROM ratings GROUP BY shop_id ) as temp on shops.shop_id=temp.shop_id
WHERE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i'), ':00') BETWEEN shop_open AND shop_close
HAVING temp.total >= '$search_total_rating'
AND address LIKE '%$search_shop_address%' AND shop_name LIKE '%$search_shop_name%' ORDER BY shop_name ASC
```

Comment: Updated to ignore the seconds.

Comment: this returns all data when i put it in my query, see my query at the top, thanks

Comment: Updated, and I ran a quick test on a dummy database, and it seems to be pulling back the correct rows.

Comment: have you only moved the WHERE clause up ? I can't get it to work. i have data within different times, so i should output something :s this is very frustrating, thanks for your help though

Comment: did i mention am using: column type: TIME

Comment: Me too, I figured that was most likely so I set mine up to use that :P Basically I moved the WHERE CONCAT... to after the JOINs, so it's not being applied as a clause for JOINing. If you want to link to a paste of some SQL dump for your tables, I can give it a go and tweak it to your exact tables :)

Comment: hey again, just been messing around again, ended up removing the between code, even tried using shop_open <= '$shop_open_now' AND shop_close < '$shop_open_now' 

But complete fail, didn't take into account its a time and midnight being 00:00 causes problems. going to bed, nearly 3am, give it ago tomorrow, thanks again